# SQL statement between date

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

This is driving me crazy and not sure what I'm missing here..

so here is my data column looks like:

```
StartDateTime:
---------------
2012-01-17 11:13:46.530
2012-01-17 11:17:22.530
2012-02-17 11:31:22.223
```

here is my query trying to get:

```
select * from tablName
where convert(varchar(10), startDateTime, 101) between '2012-01-17' and '2012-01-17'
```

based on the above I should be getting TWO rows? but it does not, it return zero rows. what will be the correct way of doing?

PS:
I've looked at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) site too:

Comment: or i can pass the dates something like this:
`01/17/2012`

Comment: What is the datatype of `StartDateTime`?

Comment: @AbuHamzah pass the date as a `datetime` data type, not char or `varchar`.

Answer (score 3):

Your query would only match dates that are between `2012-01-17 00:00:00` and `2012-01-17 00:00:00`. So, the only matches would be when the date is exactly `2012-01-17 00:00:00`.

Instead, I would do this:

```
declare @dateInput as DateTime
set @dateInput = '2012-01-17'

select * 
from tablName 
where startDateTime >= @dateInput
    and startDateTime < dateadd(day, 1, @dateInput)
```

Note: SQL Server 2008+ has a new data type [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) with no time component that can make these types of queries more readable.

Comment: `yyyy-mm-dd` is language dependant for casting to `datetime`. `yyyymmdd` is unambiguous.

Comment: if i tried both dates to be same like `startDateTime >= '2012-01-17' and startDateTime < '2012-01-17' - returns zero rows

Comment: @Abu `'2012-01-17'` equates to `'2012-01-17 00:00:00'`. See my updated answer for details.

Comment: have you tried with the same date the one what i have posted above? and if i have both dates with same date then it does not return any rows...

Answer (score 1):

There is now more information so I'll add a more appropriate answer.
The requirements are now a stored procedure passed a Date type parameter, not DateTime, and the desire is to return rows from a table based on criterion against a DateTime field named StartDateTime...

```
create procedure dbo.spGetEntriesForOneDay
@DesiredDate DateTime
as
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET @DesiredDate = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DesiredDate), 0)

SELECT Field1, Field2 -- see note 1
FROM dbo.TableName
WHERE StartDateTime >= @DesiredDate -- see note 2 
  AND StartDateTime < DATEADD(day, 1, @DesiredDate)  -- see note 3
```

**NOTE 1**: Don't use * in production code, especially in a stored procedure.  Besides being wasteful by returning columns you probably don't need and precluding the optimization of a covering index on a subset of the columns required you would need to recompile this stored procedure whenever the underlying table is altered in order to avoid unpredictable results.

**NOTE 2**: Avoid wrapping fields in functions.  A field not wrapped in a function can potentially be matched by the optimizer to an index while a field wrapped in a function never will.

**NOTE 3**: @Martin Smith and @RedFilter are correct in that .997 precision assumes DateTime datatype forever; this approach is more future proof because is makes no assumptions of data type precision.

Comment: I can't change the datatype and it has to be datetime only... its a bug in production so just by changing datatype will create more problems for others...

Comment: ok - I thought your parameter was a Date date type, I'll modify the example to be DateTime

Comment: thanks for reply but I'm not sure what is different answer from RedFilter?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a datetime field (I'm guessing).
Don't forget the time:

```
select * from tablName
where startDateTime between '2012-01-17' and '2012-01-17 23:59:59.997'
```

Comment: And if they are using `datetime2`? Or later alter the column to that?

Comment: @Tahbaza: the user will be passing a parameters as date(01/17/2012) not datetime (2012-01-17 23:59:59.997)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateDiff function in the where clause. It would look like this:

```
select col1, col2 from tablName where DateDiff(day, startDateTime, @DesiredDate) = 0
```